# How to get hardware information of (in-build) microphone?

Tags: javascript, web, microphone

Is it possible to read the hardware information (at least the name) of  the (in-build) microphone while a user is recording an audio file on my website?

Is that possible with JavaScript or is there another way to solve this problem? I searched the web but could only find scripts for recording with JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Newer version**: Available in Firefox, MS Edge, and Chrome 45 with experimental flag.

Using the standard `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`, you can get a list of available sources. Each source has a `kind` property, as well as a `label`.

```js
var stream;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true })
.then(s => (stream = s), e => console.log(e.message))
.then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices())
.then(devices => {
  stream && stream.stop();
  console.log(devices.length + " devices.");
  devices.forEach(d => console.log(d.kind + ": " + d.label));
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>" };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

**Documentation & Related**

- `navigator.mediaDevices` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices
- The "Media Capture and Streams" specification - http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#mediadevices
- Demo of selecting input source by Sam Dutton - https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

The last demo works in regular Chrome thanks to the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill.

Comment: In Chrome 45, try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/864jm6zk/) instead. getUserMedia isn't working in stack overflow code snippets in that browser for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

### Outdated API

This answer uses an API that is non-standard, with limited browser support. It works in current Chrome as of writing, but will not be adopted in future versions of other browsers, and may be going away in Chrome. For a solution with more widespread support, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31758598/610573

---

Using `MediaStreamTrack.getSources()`, you can get a list of available sources. Each source has a `kind` property, as well as a `label`.

```
MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfos) {
    for (var i = 0; i != sourceInfos.length; ++i) {
        var thisSource = sourceInfos[i];
        console.log('stream type: '+thisSource.kind+', label: '+thisSource.label); 
        // example: stream type: audio, label: internal microphone
    }
});
```

**Documentation & Related**

- `MediaStreamTrack` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack
- "Capturing Audio & Video in HTML5" on HTML5Rocks.com - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
- Demo of selecting input source by Sam Dutton - https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/

Comment: `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` is outdated and only works in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: @jib I don't know about "outdated", and it appears to be available in Firefox. A different [adapter.js](https://github.com/Temasys/AdapterJS) also shims support for `MediaStreamTrack.getSources`, and I don't see much in the documentation to support the assertion that this method is going deprecated or going away any time soon. Also, no big deal, but I thought it was kind of weird that you copied the wording from my answer.

Comment: @ChrisBaker It is [not available in Firefox](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/dom/webidl/MediaStreamTrack.webidl?rev=e9a8fe34405c#17), and never has been. It was removed from the standard between [October 17. 2013](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/archives/20131017/getusermedia.html#idl-def-MediaStreamTrack) and  [November 5. 2013](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/archives/20131105/getusermedia.html#idl-def-MediaStreamTrack), i.e. outdated by ~2 years. Chrome 45 implements its replacement, so lets all converge on the standard. The adapter.js linked is outdated/unofficial.

Comment: @ChrisBaker sorry I didn't mean to weird you out borrowing the structure of your answer. I almost edited your answer, before realizing that that would probably have been rude. My intent is merely to correct information, and by having the answers look similar, I hoped people would see the symmetry and that every piece linked to has an updated version (except the hacks article, which I guess I should have a chat about with them).

Comment: @jib It did weird me out, but I got over it :)

Comment: I edited my answer to add a disclaimer, and the information is good to know, because I'm using the method in my answer for a semi-experimental/semi-production tool. Looks like we'll need to modify our approach. @Kami, be sure to note the change. If you change your selected answer, I'll remove mine.

Comment: @ChrisBaker thx but do not remove your answer maybe that would also help other :)

Comment: I agree with @Kami that the legacy information is useful, and Chrome hasn't yet switched over. Thanks for editing it.