# webRTC: How to get external microphones to work?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, microphone, getusermedia

In a working webRTC app (voice only) I came across a weird bug: When prompted to select the audio input via `getUserMedia()` it seems that any other microphone but the built in will work.

Although the selection results in no immediate errors, there is no signal transferred when a webRTC connection is established - the line stays silent. If I select the internal microphone, everything works as expected.

I tested this with Chrome and Firefox to no avail.

Anybody more information on this behavior?

**EDIT SEPTEMBER, 13th**

More info on test setup: Chrome 45, with experimental features on. Chrome will list the external audio sources via `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices`but will result in no sound at all when anything else but external mic is chosen from gUM input select.

**The question: Is there ANYBODY that managed to get an external mic to work with webRTC?**

Comment: Does the microphone show up when do use the deviceEnumeration API? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610945/how-to-choose-input-video-device-for-webrtc

Comment: It lists the mic in the input select that pops up as soon as getUserMedia is invoked, but I have not tried deviceEnumeration yet. Will look into this.

Comment: Firefox does not yet support devices selection with getUserMedia, so, for now, rule that out.

Comment: @xdumaine, why does firefox then bother showing the selection in the first place? bug?

Comment: xdumaine - Firefox should support device selection just fine. @BenjaminTrent - that device enumeration link is outdated by two years. Instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31758598/918910

Comment: Glad to see an update :). I have not messed directly with that API.

Comment: @jib are you talking about the browser device selection menu, or choosing devices with getUserMedia? Has that changed in the last couple weeks? I was testing with nightlies just a couple weeks ago and it still had no support, for example with https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/. Device enumeration worked, but no matter waht was passed to gUM, it used the device default. I'm remote right now and don't have a second media device to test with.

Comment: @xdumaine the deviceId constraint was added to gUM in Firefox 42 [two months ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1037389). I'm using your link right now in Firefox 42 for android, and it works to switch between front and back camera using that page.

Comment: @jib Camera is not what I am questioning: I am questioning microphones. I am using the latest Firefox on Mac and it definitely does *not* work. If something other than internal mic is chosen, there is silence.

Comment: @jib But I confirm the names using the example above are now more descriptive than before (proper names instead of "microphone 1"). Unfortunately, that does not solve my question.

Comment: @Armin note that Firefox release is 40 right now. deviceId gUM constraint requires 42+ (Firefox Developer Edition or Nightly). Is it working to pick microphone in Firefox's built-in device selector that pops up as part of the gUM permission prompt at least? That should work in any version.

Comment: @jib No, that's exactly the issue. Neither Firefox nor Chrome (Mac) will work as expected when I select any other Mic than the internal (built in).

Comment: As a side note: It is said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754529/how-to-get-hardware-information-of-in-build-microphone/31758598#31758598 that this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/864jm6zk/ (navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) would work in Chrome 45. Not for me. (Mac)

Comment: @ArminHierstetter it works in Chrome 45 only if you enable the Experimental Features flag.

Comment: @xdumaine Ahhh, thanks, stupid me!

Comment: @Benjamin To finally answer you question: Yes, Chrome lists the external audio device. But when I select it, there is no sound.

Comment: @jib the example I linked above does not work in Firefox 42.0 for mac. It always uses the camera set in the permissions dialog. It does not matter what device is passed into gUM.

Comment: @jib I've also created a basic example using `deviceId` constraint and it has no effect in FF 42 on mac.

Comment: @xdumaine I've [submitted a fix for that page](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/pull/647) (the device passed in should still be the default though). Make sure you use the form `deviceId: { exact: id }` to restrict choices.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution.

The reaons why no sound was picked up is rather simple: webRTC expects the mircophone attached to input channel 1 or 2 in case you use a microphone connected with an *audio interface* to your computer.

I have not found a way to tell my webRTC app to chose a different input channel, so the mic simply has to be channel 1 or 2.

BTW: The same is true for Skype. Any mic connected with an audio interface needs to be plugged into channel 1 – otherwise it will not be recognized as Skype seems to use channel 1 as default, too.